# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

I writing code for adding roles to users in my asp.net core project

Here is my Roles controller.

```
public class RolesController : Controller
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    UserManager<AspNetUsers> _userManager;
    public RolesController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<AspNetUsers> userManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public IActionResult Index() => View(_roleManager.Roles.ToList());

    public IActionResult Create() => View();
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(name));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(name);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (role != null)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult UserList() => View(_userManager.Users.ToList());

    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        AspNetUsers user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if(user!=null)
        {
            // получем список ролей пользователя
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            ChangeRoleViewModel model = new ChangeRoleViewModel
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                UserEmail = user.Email,
                UserRoles = userRoles,
                AllRoles = allRoles
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId, List<string> roles)
    {

        AspNetUsers user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if(user!=null)
        {

            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();

            var addedRoles = roles.Except(userRoles);

            var removedRoles = userRoles.Except(roles);

            await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, addedRoles);

            await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, removedRoles);

            return RedirectToAction("UserList");
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

But when I run app and going to Roles controller. I get this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'VchasnoCrm.Controllers.RolesController'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

How I can fix this?

Comment: Can you show the `services.AddIdentity` line in your `Startup.cs` file?

Comment: Already fixed it and write answer @S.Akbari

Comment: I want to call out that I had major issues with a similar issue, I assumed RoleManager used the IdentityUser, vs needing to use  RoleManager<IdentityRole>. Thanks all for the answers!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Net Core 3.1 there are two different overload of ASP.NET Core Identity, first version named DefaultIdentity, You have not opportunity to set simultaneously User and Roles, so syntax look as

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => ...
```

Second version of Identity use User and Roles and look as

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => ...
```

It's different version of identity, first include IdentityUI, second not include IdentityUI.
But, you CAN include roles to first version, if you add Roles services as

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>...).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()...
```

If you have included Roles services to your set of services, you can inject Roles to Configure method as

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> identityDbContextOptions, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
```

this error message usually appear if you inject

```
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
```

in any place of your project without adding IdentityRole services (by first or second way).

Comment: Give full examples without "..."

Comment: @Harvey, there are no other steps or required text elements.  Simply add ".AddRoles<IdentityRole>()" to the line in your class after the closing ")" of the IdentityUser options.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the same entity on .AddRoles and when you inject it, even if there's an inheritance between the classes.

Answer (score 15):

I have encountered a similar issue using .net core 3.0, identity Server 4 & angular SPA default template (Project auto-generated by Rider).

In my case `Startup.cs` contained:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I had to add `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` and change it to:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 12):

In `startup.cs` file, you must add `.addRoles<IdentityRole>()` in one of the services:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<Usuarios>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() //Line that can help you
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 10):

So for make this works, I need to add this row to Startup.cs file

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And Change my Roles controller like this

```
public class RolesController : Controller
{
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    public RolesController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public IActionResult Index() => View(_roleManager.Roles.ToList());

    public IActionResult Create() => View();
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(name));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }
        }
        return View(name);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
    {
        IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (role != null)
        {
            IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public IActionResult UserList() => View(_userManager.Users.ToList());

    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if(user!=null)
        {
            // получем список ролей пользователя
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            ChangeRoleViewModel model = new ChangeRoleViewModel
            {
                UserId = user.Id,
                UserEmail = user.Email,
                UserRoles = userRoles,
                AllRoles = allRoles
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId, List<string> roles)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if(user!=null)
        {
            // получем список ролей пользователя
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            // получаем все роли
            var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            // получаем список ролей, которые были добавлены
            var addedRoles = roles.Except(userRoles);
            // получаем роли, которые были удалены
            var removedRoles = userRoles.Except(roles);

            await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, addedRoles);

            await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, removedRoles);

            return RedirectToAction("UserList");
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Net Core 3.1, you need to configure helper functions for identity services. To do this, you need to creates a new instance of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilder.To activate RoleManager service -

1. Go to your startup.cs file.
2. In my case, syntax look like as -

   ```
   var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
         builder.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
   ```